# asp.net webforms authorization not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a legacy web forms app that includes a page for when the user forgets the password. In my web.config file I have the following in order to allow the user to access that page without needing to log in.

```
<location path="ForgotPassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

However, when I try to access ForgotPassword.aspx, it redirects me to Default.aspx. The strange thing is that this used to work and no changes were made when it broke. I have literally tried everything at this point to restore access to ForgotPassword.aspx. What's going on, and how do I fix this?